# Cumulative count in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, count, cumulative-sum

I am trying to export a `cumulative` `count` based off two columns in a `pandas` `df`.

An example is the `df` below. I'm trying to export a `count` based off `Value` and `Count`. So when the `count` increase I want attribute that to the adjacent `value`

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Value' : ['A','A','B','C','D','A','B','A'],
    'Count' : [0,1,1,2,3,3,4,5],
    }) 

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I have used this:

```
for val in ['A','B','C','D']:
    cond = df.Value.eq(val) & df.Count.eq(int)
    df.loc[cond, 'Count_' + val] = cond[cond].cumsum()
```

If I alter `int` to a specific number it will return the count. But I need this to read any number as the `Count` column keeps increasing.

My intended output is:

```
  Value  Count  A_Count  B_Count  C_Count  D_Count
0     A      0        0        0        0        0
1     A      1        1        0        0        0
2     B      1        1        0        0        0
3     C      2        1        0        1        0
4     D      3        1        0        1        1
5     A      3        1        0        1        1
6     B      4        1        1        1        1
7     A      5        2        1        1        1
```

So the `count` increase on the `second row` so `1` to `Value A`. `Count` increases again on `row 4` and it's the first time for `Value C` so `1`. Same again for `rows 5` and `7`. The `count` increases on `row 8` so `A` becomes `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `str.get_dummies` and `diff` and `cumsum`

```
In [262]: df['Value'].str.get_dummies().multiply(df['Count'].diff().gt(0), axis=0).cumsum()
Out[262]:
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0
3  1  0  1  0
4  1  0  1  1
5  1  0  1  1
6  1  1  1  1
7  2  1  1  1
```

Which is

```
In [266]: df.join(df['Value'].str.get_dummies()
                  .multiply(df['Count'].diff().gt(0), axis=0)
                  .cumsum().add_suffix('_Count'))
Out[266]:
  Value  Count  A_Count  B_Count  C_Count  D_Count
0     A      0        0        0        0        0
1     A      1        1        0        0        0
2     B      1        1        0        0        0
3     C      2        1        0        1        0
4     D      3        1        0        1        1
5     A      3        1        0        1        1
6     B      4        1        1        1        1
7     A      5        2        1        1        1
```

Comment: Jeez that was quick @Zero. Thanks